# How do I perform inter-row operations within a pandas.dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

**How do I write the nested `for` loop to access every other row with respect to a row within a `pandas.dataframe`?**

I am trying to perform some operations between rows in a pandas.dataframe
The operation for my example code is calculating Euclidean distances between each row with each other row.
The results are then saved into a some list in the form 
`[(row_reference, name, dist)]`.

I understand how to access each row in a pandas.dataframe using `df.itterrows()` but I'm not sure how to access every other row with respect to the current row in order to perform the inter-row operation.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import math

df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': "Bill", 'c1': 3, 'c2': 8}, {'name': "James", 'c1': 4, 'c2': 12},
                   {'name': "John", 'c1': 12, 'c2': 26}])

#Euclidean distance function where x1=c1_row1 ,x2=c1_row2, y1=c2_row1, #y2=c2_row2
def edist(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    dist = math.sqrt(math.pow((x1 - x2),2) + math.pow((y1 - y2),2))
    return dist

# Calculate Euclidean distance for one row (e.g. Bill) against each other row
# (e.g. "James" and "John"). Save results to a list (N_name, dist).

all_results = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    results = []
#   secondary loop to look for OTHER rows with respect to the current row
#        results.append(row2['name'],edist())
    all_results.append(row,results)
```

I hope to perform some operation `edist()` on all rows with respect to the current row/index.

I expect the loop to do the following:

```py
In[1]:
result = []
result.append(['James',edist(3,4,8,12)])
result.append(['John',edist(3,12,8,26)])
results_all=[]
results_all.append([0,result])
result2 = []
result2.append(['John',edist(4,12,12,26)])
result2.append(['Bill',edist(4,3,12,8)])
results_all.append([1,result2])
result3 = []
result3.append(['Bill',edist(12,3,26,8)])
result3.append(['James', edist(12,4,26,12)])
results_all.append([2,result3])
results_all
```

With the following expected resulting output:

```py
OUT[1]:
[[0, [['James', 4.123105625617661], ['John', 20.12461179749811]]],
 [1, [['John', 16.1245154965971], ['Bill', 4.123105625617661]]],
 [2, [['Bill', 20.12461179749811], ['James', 16.1245154965971]]]]
```

Comment: Can you post desired output?

Comment: Code cannot be runnable as Python power function does not use `^`.

Comment: You can always do another `iterrows` and trim the results after, though it is better to use a vectorized approach instead of `apply` your own function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you data is not too long, you can check out scipy's `distance_matrix`:

```
all_results = pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix(df[['c1','c2']],df[['c1','c2']]),
                           index=df['name'],
                           columns=df['name'])
```

Output:

```
name        Bill      James       John
name                                  
Bill    0.000000   4.123106  20.124612
James   4.123106   0.000000  16.124515
John   20.124612  16.124515   0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider `shift` and avoid any rowwise looping. And because you run straightforward arithmetic, run the expression directly on columns using help of `numpy` for vectorized calculation.

```
import numpy as np

df = (df.assign(c1_shift = lambda x: x['c1'].shift(1),
                c2_shift = lambda x: x['c2'].shift(1))
     )

df['dist'] = np.sqrt(np.power(df['c1'] - df['c1_shift'], 2) + 
                     np.power(df['c2'] - df['c2_shift'], 2))

print(df)
#     name  c1  c2  c1_shift  c2_shift       dist
# 0   Bill   3   8       NaN       NaN        NaN
# 1  James   4  12       3.0       8.0   4.123106
# 2   John  12  26       4.0      12.0  16.124515
```

Should you want every row combination with each other, consider a cross join on itself and query out reverse duplicates:

```
df = (pd.merge(df.assign(key=1), df.assign(key=1), on="key")
        .query("name_x < name_y")
        .drop(columns=['key'])
     )

df['dist'] = np.sqrt(np.power(df['c1_x'] - df['c1_y'], 2) +
                     np.power(df['c2_x'] - df['c2_y'], 2))

print(df)    
#   name_x  c1_x  c2_x name_y  c1_y  c2_y       dist
# 1   Bill     3     8  James     4    12   4.123106
# 2   Bill     3     8   John    12    26  20.124612
# 5  James     4    12   John    12    26  16.124515
```